# how to fix 504 Gateway Time-out on AWS ECS in my Django app?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx

**Explanation**

I am hosting Django app on ECS on AWS. I am using nginx and gunicorn on production It happens very often that I see status 499 and then 504 with timeout error. Below yuo can see my container logs. During that time backend does not respond for several minutes and after restart it changes status to 200 again.

I have created

```
2023/09/06 14:42:52 [error] 9#9: *1348 upstream timed out (110: Operation timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.0.10.112, server: , request: "GET /api/tasks/logs/8b9ad2d4-b63a-4782-83c2-940764c04eb1/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tasks/logs/8b9ad2d4-b63a-4782-88c2-940764u04eb1/", host: "admin.myapp.com"
10.0.11.207 - - [06/Sep/2023:14:42:48 +0000] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
10.0.10.112 - - [06/Sep/2023:14:42:49 +0000] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 504 167 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
```

My CPU and memory usage never exceeds 20% (usually it is around 8-12%). Only few people are using this application. My health check settings and load balancer look like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

nginx.config

```
upstream myapp_backend {
  server ${APP_HOST}:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myapp_backend; 
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        client_max_body_size 200M;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/app/web/static/;
    }

}
```

Dockerfile-nginx

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/nginx/nginx:1.24-alpine
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /nginx.conf.template
CMD ["/bin/sh" , "-c" , "envsubst '$APP_HOST' < /nginx.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
EXPOSE 80
```

**Question**

Could you please help me to figure out why nginx crashes and how to potentially fix it? As you see I changed default settings in health check and increased timeout in target group but it does not help. It happens twice or three times a day but it is annoying.